# C++ standard library Serial port (UART) interface

Tags: c++, std

I would like to read/write data from/to a serial port in c++, but I would like to have my code as portable as possible. I am currently working on a window environment and using only std function (windows.h was never #include'ed).
Is there any portable, **correct** (i.e. not #ifdef, not boost) way to interface the serial port?

Assuming the answer to the above is no, is there's any protable package that can preform this (basic) task?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard C(++) libraries do not provide a specialized interface to your serial port. Yet you *can* use the generic I/O (such as `<iostream>`) given that your operating system supports file-based access to the port. This is the case for Unix/Linux via the usual files in `/dev/tty...` and Windows via the reserved `COM1` device names etc.

To set and get the port's parameters (baud rate and such), you still need to use platform-specific API. This will probably be Winapi for Windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx) and could be `termios` for Linux (note that there are multiple interfaces under Linux; `termios` is standardized in POSIX).

As a portable library, Qt provides the `QSerialPort` class, for example.